# Element 'script', attribute 'crossorigin': The attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, magento2.3.1, script

After installing customer attribute extension from Bsscommerce they added another addon module. It then broke frontend of site so they disabled all of their modules but the error still persists. I've tried to disable a few more modules but no luck. Below is the error on front end it does not effect admin. Any idea how to debug or fix this trace stack error? Thanks in advance.

I'm using Magento v2.3.1 with Luma Theme with PHP 7.1 MariaDB 10.1

I have installed several extensions without issue from vendors such as Amasty, Mageworx, Mageplaza etc.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'script', attribute 'crossorigin': The attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed.
Line: 39

Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 816

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 816


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'script', attribute 'crossorigin': The attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed.
Line: 39

Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 816

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 816

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000073c344cf00000000146335d9#, array(), NULL, '/home/325992.clo...', '%message%\nLine: ...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000073c344cf00000000146335d9#, array(), NULL, '/home/325992.clo...', '%message%\nLine: ...')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/home/325992.clo...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000073c344cf00000000146335d9#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/home/325992.clo...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000073c344cf00000000146335d9#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/home/325992.clo...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000073c344cf00000000146335d9#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:xs...', 'layout_merged', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:476]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend_...', '<!--\r\n    <refer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:457]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(array()) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:171]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(&Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000073c3467000000000146335d9#, 'home') called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php:74]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:24]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#, &Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000073c3467000000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#27 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000073c3447200000000146335d9#, &Closure#0000000073c3441200000000146335d9#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#29 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000073c3447200000000146335d9#, &Closure#0000000073c3441200000000146335d9#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000073c345e800000000146335d9#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000073c345aa00000000146335d9#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

I also get these errors in the system and debug log files

```
[2020-01-14 11:55:19] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4e1068c6123bfaf5dad1b5e6b31c1241b and handles default, cms_noroute_index, cms_page_view, cms_noroute_index_id_no-route, algolia_search_handle, algolia_search_handle_with_topsearch: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'script', attribute 'crossorigin': The attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed.
Line: 36

Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 813

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 813
 [] []
[2020-01-14 11:55:19] main.ERROR: Element 'script', attribute 'crossorigin': The attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed.
Line: 36

Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 813

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 813
 [] []
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to search the line `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` in the Bsscommerce module and replace it with `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`.
Then search for `crossorigin` attribute for the `script` tag and remove that attribute. Clean cache, deploy static content and check again.

Seems like old kind of code.